# Property expansion in soapui returns only string not the expected value

Tags: soapui

I am trying to create a dynamic property during processing based on property expansion in soapui.

In the property, variable name is `pkSSN` and dynamic value is `${createIP -abc#Response#//en:name/num/text()}`

```
Where:
1. createIP -abc is test step name
2. Response (tag is present in the response of the  test step)
3. //en:name/num/text()   xpath of the value
```

It should return the value in the ssn tag like '`123456789`' but it this  `[${createIP -abc#Response#//en:name/num/text()}].`

I am following this link "https://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/property-expansion.html#2-Dynamic-Properties" but still negative output. Can someone please suggest me what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Are you using property expansion in a Groovy test step or somewhere else?

Comment: It is difficult suggest anything without seeing the response and which data are you trying to extract.

Comment: which version of SOAPUI do you use ?

Comment: did you build it on your own or did you use SOAPUI pro facilities ? you may edit your question and add the createIP-OSIClaimant step response, so we could check that nothing is missing ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

i have created 2 request and it has below 2 request

1) ConversionRate

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <web:ConversionRate>
     <web:FromCurrency>DZD</web:FromCurrency>
     <web:ToCurrency>ALL</web:ToCurrency>
  </web:ConversionRate>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

2) SOAP Request second

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
 <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
  <web:ConversionRate>
     <web:FromCurrency>USD</web:FromCurrency>
     <web:ToCurrency>${ConversionRate#Request#//web:ConversionRate[1]/web:FromCurrency[1]}</web:ToCurrency>
   </web:ConversionRate>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

so the command

```
${ConversionRate#Request#//web:ConversionRate[1]/web:FromCurrency[1]}
```

is able to retrieve what you are trying to achieve

i think you are missing the namespace